# Use Openrowset to import data into SQL Server 2014 Express from an Access database

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, openrowset, isam

I see similar topics already posted but none gives me an answer. I am trying to import data from an Access database, not Excel.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 
              'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};
              Database=C:\Users\td\Dropbox\Utilization Reports\DB\201606\IMA_0216_v2k.mdb', 
              'select * from BackupLabels')
```

And here is the error message I get:

> OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)"
>   returned message "Could not find installable ISAM.".

I had the same error when linking to an Excel file. I used `Regsvr32.exe` to associate the `.dll` file using this site (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/209805) and that worked, but when I link to an Access database it doesn't.  I tried to find a `.dll` file for Access but couldn't.

Does anyone have any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Your second argument to `OPENROWSET` looks wrong. It appears to be an ODBC connection string when, if I recall correctly, it should just be the database path and credentials (e.g., `..., 'C:\Users\td\Dropbox\Utilization Reports\DB\201606\IMA_0216_v2k.mdb';'admin';'', ...`).

Comment: Have you installed the appropriate Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010?  64 bit or 32 bit version?  Are you attempting to import in a 32 bit process or 64 bit process? Are you potentially mixing up 32 & 64?

Comment: Oops I think ACE.OLEDB.12.0 is actually Access Database Engine 2007 according to wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Jet_Database_Engine)  If you have 2010 installed but not 2007 you will have to uninstall 2010 install 2007 and then reinstall 2010+ the older must be installed prior to newer versions if you are going to use that provider.  Otherwise try the new providers e.g ACE 14.0 for 2010 , 50.0 for 2013..... And still pay attention to 64 vs 32 bit

Comment: @Matt - 2010 and later versions of the OLEDB provider register themselves as `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` even though they are actually 14.0, etc.. so uninstalling/reinstalling should not be necessary.

Comment: @GordThompson  my own experience with the access database engines has been contradictory to what you have stated and I have infact had to install in the order I mentioned. the wikipedia article states that 2010 (ACE 14) discontinued support for  older versions of Jet(1.0-2.0) but still maintained some support for 3.0-4.0 which should include office 2007.  2013 dropped support everything except 4.0. So some backwards compatibility was maintained during the new releases and some not...............

Comment: Appreciate your help guys!  I tried all of the above and none worked.  To answer your questions, I am running a 32 bit system but don't know if I'm importing a 32 or 64 bit process.  How do I tell?  I have installed and reinstalled Access Database Engine 2010 and tried other providers.  If you can think of anything else I'd be willing to give it a try.  Thanks again.

Comment: Just wanted to let you guys know I found a solution - Use OPENDATASOURCE instead of OPENROWSET.  Here is the query:

Select *
FROM OPENDATASOURCE ('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','Data Source = "C:\Users\td\Dropbox\Utilization Reports\DB\201606\Careplus\IMA_0216_v2k.mdb"' )...Backuplabels